# Very Simple Lambda /Event Parameters Prob

Tags: c#, parameters, lambda

So simply I am trying to pass MyReader into the EventHandler function. I know I have to use the " => " operator, but I still get errors. Here's my code:

```
     private void PrintButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
     {
      StringReader MyReader= new StringReader(StrTxt);
      PD.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler(this.pd_PrintPage);
     }

     private void pd_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs ev)
     {
     }
```

Comment: Well, what errors do you get? Give us a clue here...

Comment: The PrintPageEventHandler doesn't take a StringReader... so how are you planning to pass it into the function? csharpler's solution works to accomplish what you specifically asked but I do wonder if something else is going on here...

Comment: Shown below is an error

Answer (score 4):

Use it as an additional argument to the sender and the eventargs:

```
PD.PrintPage += (sender, ev) => this.pd_PrintPage(sender, ev, MyReader);

//...

private void pd_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs ev, StringReader reader)
{
    //...
}
```

You specify the arguments `PD.PrintPage` has (`object sender, PrintPageEventArgs ev`) in the parentheses, and then the function you want to use after the `=>` operator.

Comment: I'm Receiving this error...

A local variable named 'sender' cannot be declared in this scope because it would give a different meaning to 'sender', which is already used in a 'parent or current' scope to denote something else

Comment: then just use another name, for example just `s`:

`PD.PrintPage += (s, ev) => this.pd_PrintPage(s, ev, MyReader);`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass in extra objects, you'll want to expose them as parameters:

```
private void pd_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs ev, StringReader reader)
 {
 }
```

Then you can use:

```
 PD.PrintPage += (sender, args) => this.pd_PrintPage(sender, args, MyReader);
```

Note that you don't *have* to use => here, but yes: it is *convenient* to do it that way. There are at least two other ways of doing the same thing more verbosely.